# How to delete legend in ggplot with reression model?

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression

I'd like to ask how to delete legend in ggplot with regression model.

I already added `theme(legend.position = "None")`

but the legend cannot be deleted. Could you tell me what I was doing wrong?

**Extra question!!
In my current code, how to change the symbol size and shape between N0 and N1? I want more bigger size of 'open circle', and 'closed square' shape.**

Many thanks!!!

[image]

```
ggplot(data=x, aes(x=agw, y=pgw)) + 
  geom_point (data=x, aes(x=agw, y=pgw, color=Nitrogen)) + 
  stat_smooth(method = 'lm', se=FALSE, color="Black") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Dark gray","Black")) +
  theme(legend.position = "None") +
  geom_text(x=30, y=70, label="", size=3.5, col="Black") + 
  geom_text(x=30, y=60, label="", size=3.5, col="Black") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,80,10),limits = c(0,80)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,80,10), limits = c(0,80)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
```

Comment: Put `theme(legend.position = "None")` after `theme_bw()`.

Comment: Your question regarding symbol size is unclear. Maybe `geom_point(aes(x=agw, y=pgw, shape=Nitrogen), size = 5)`?

Comment: I solved it!!!!! Many thanks!! Roland

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work in lack of reproducible data. Be careful that functions like `theme_bw()` use to remove previous `theme()` settings as mentioned by @Ronald. So it is better to add in the final part of the plot. For shapes, you can enable `shape` in `aes()` like this and format with `scale_shape_manual()` (the numbers inside belong to the shape you want):

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
ggplot(data=x, aes(x=agw, y=pgw)) + 
  geom_point (data=x, aes(x=agw, y=pgw, color=Nitrogen,shape=Nitrogen,size=3)) + 
  stat_smooth(method = 'lm', se=FALSE, color="Black") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Dark gray","Black")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(1,15))+
  geom_text(x=30, y=70, label="", size=3.5, col="Black") + 
  geom_text(x=30, y=60, label="", size=3.5, col="Black") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,80,10),limits = c(0,80)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,80,10), limits = c(0,80)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        legend.position = 'none')
```

Comment: Yes!! now I totally got it!! Many thanks!! You people are my heroes!!!

Answer (score 1):

For the legend: add the argument `show.legend = F`  inside `geom_point`. For the different point size: can you give us an example of your dataset? We may need to reshape it.

```
ggplot(data=x, aes(x=agw, y=pgw)) + 
  geom_point (data=x, aes(x=agw, y=pgw, color=Nitrogen), show.legend = F) + 
  stat_smooth(method = 'lm', se=FALSE, color="Black") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Dark gray","Black")) +
  theme(legend.position = "None") +
  geom_text(x=30, y=70, label="", size=3.5, col="Black") + 
  geom_text(x=30, y=60, label="", size=3.5, col="Black") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,80,10),limits = c(0,80)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,80,10), limits = c(0,80)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
```